# Read all fields of a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, read.csv

I have a problem reading a csv file. Each line of the csv file is separated by ,
My edge.csv file looks like this:

```
source,target,genre
apple,banana,28
strawberry,mango,30
so on.....
```

So this is my code for read edge.csv file:

```
def read_net(filename):
    g = nx.Graph()
    with open(filename,encoding="ISO-8859-1",newline="") as f:
        f.readline()
        for l in f:
            l = l.split(",")
            g.add_edge(l[0], l[1], l[2])    //my error is here
    return g
read_net("edge.csv")
```

My code don't work because my code can't read "genre" field of edge.csv file.
It's like my code only reads the first two fields and not the third one as well. Why?
This is my error:

```
TypeError: Graph.add_edge() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

how can i read all three fields of the edge.csv file?

Comment: please print `l` from inside the loop before the line giving the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
Graph.add_edge(u_of_edge, v_of_edge, **attr)
```

Add an edge between u and v.

The nodes u and v will be automatically added if they are not already in the graph.

Edge attributes can be specified with keywords or by directly accessing the edge’s attribute dictionary.

So you should build a graph using `source` and `target` with `genre` that is not clear at all what it should be? Is it the weight of the connection? A numeric feature associated with the connection?

```
def read_net(filename):
    g = nx.Graph()
    with open(filename,encoding="ISO-8859-1",newline="") as f:
        f.readline()
        for l in f:
            source, destination, genre = l.split(",")
            g.add_edge(source, destination)
    return g
read_net("edge.csv")
```

For now this will get you started, when you find out more info on the `genre` field you can think about how to incorporate it into the graph.

---

In case `genre` is the weight of the connection:

```
def read_net(filename):
    g = nx.Graph()
    with open(filename,encoding="ISO-8859-1",newline="") as f:
        f.readline()
        for l in f:
            source, destination, genre = l.split(",")
            g.add_edge(source, destination, weight=genre)
    return g
read_net("edge.csv")
```

Comment: genre is the weight of the connection

Comment: @Elly put more info in the answer

Comment: genre is the weight of the connection between source and target. I want read all field "source" , "destination" and "genre" in my csv file and make an nx.Graph with its.

Comment: @Elly does my answer solve your problem (I added a new section in the end)?

Comment: You are welcome Elly, in the future try to give as much information as possible when asking questions here. I hope you good luck on the rest of your project!